# Razor intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am on visual studio2012 my intellisense does not provide me auto-completion in razor views with Helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to download and install the Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012.

> ASP.NET Razor Tooling
>
> With this release you will also get great editor support for editing Razor views in MVC. This includes features such as syntax highlighting, Intellisense etc.

The tool can be accessed **[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)**. Hopefully this will help

Comment: Thks very much I'm going to try it ;)

Comment: Thanks Izzy this was easy to do. I have download it and then have an Intellisense support